# Tried to remove the Entit yManager, but none was set

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I am getting run time error in Play Framework 2.5 (Java) :

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tried to remove the Entit yManager, but none was set.]]
        at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:280)
        at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:206)
        at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:160)
        at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:188)
        at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:98)
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:100)
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:99)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:344)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:343)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tried to remove the EntityManager, but none was set.
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:593)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
        at scala.concurrent.java8.FuturesConvertersImpl$CF.apply(FutureConvertersImpl.scala:21)
        at scala.concurrent.java8.FuturesConvertersImpl$CF.apply(FutureConvertersImpl.scala:18)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
        at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:63)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tried to remove the EntityManager, but none was set.
        at play.db.jpa.JPAEntityManagerContext.pop(JPAEntityManagerContext.java:74)
        at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.withTransaction(DefaultJPAApi.java:155)
        at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.withTransaction(DefaultJPAApi.java:195)
        at play.db.jpa.TransactionalAction.call(TransactionalAction.java:25)
        at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$7.apply(JavaAction.scala:108)
        at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$7.apply(JavaAction.scala:108)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
        at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:56)
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:70)
```

Below is the code :

```
@Transactional
public Result logincheck(){

    Form<User> loginForm = Form.form(User.class).bindFromRequest();

    User user = loginForm.get();

    User searchUser = UserDao.findUser(user);

    if (searchUser != null){
        return ok(homepage.render());
    }

    return ok(login.render(loginForm));
}
```

In class UserDao:

```
public static User findUser(User user){

    EntityManager em = jpaApi.em();

    TypedQuery<User> query = JPA.em().createQuery("select u.* from [RL].[dbo].[userdetails] u where u.userid = :username and u.password = :password", User.class);

    query.setParameter("username", user.userid);
    query.setParameter("password", user.password);

    try{
        return (User) query.getSingleResult();


    } catch(NoResultException e){
        return null;

    }


}
```

Comment: Clearly "select u.* from [RL].[dbo].[userdetails]" is invalid JPQL. Not necessarily the problem you cite here, but anyway ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply Neil. I have tried to rewrite statement but not able to resolve the problem. Can you please write the correct one. My class name is User and table name is userdetails, schema = dao (SQL Server)

Comment: _SELECT u FROM User u ..._   This is apparent from any basic JPA tutorial

Answer (score 3):

We found this issue while working with play2.5. We fixed it by adding 
the persistence.xml file into the project as specified here : [Play 2.5 JavaJPA creating a persistence unit](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaJPA#creating-a-persistence-unit)

and adding the following in the application.conf:

```
jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using JPA.em() and jpaApi in the same method. Actually this should be the same entity manager. Starting from play 2.5 the proper way is jpaApi, JPA.em() is deprecated. You should take care to inject jpaApi.

The code may be like this:

```
public static User findUser(User user) {
    JPAApi jpaApi = Play.current().injector().instanceOf(JPAApi.class);
    EntityManager em = jpaApi.em();
    TypedQuery<User> query = em.createQuery("select u.* from [RL].[dbo].[userdetails] u where u.userid = :username and u.password = :password", User.class);
    ...
}
```

You can read more [here](http://www.codepreference.com/2016/07/guice-dependency-injection-in-play.htmlhttp://) about dependency injection in Play